# get id of each row in onItemClickListener in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, onitemclicklistener

I need to get the id of each row in listview.onItemClickListener. This would have been much easier with position but I need to use a search bar in my app. The problem with position is that if I search for item2 and I press it, the onItemClickListener will see that it's first in the row(position 0) and it will set layout 1 instead of layout 2.

I thought about getting the Id of each row or something like that and based on the id set the layout.

I searched on google but I don't seem to find anything useful at all

How do I do that

My MainActivity:

```kotlin
package com.biskyy.caietdecantarikt



import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        val filter = findViewById<View>(R.id.srcFilter) as EditText

        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resources.getStringArray(R.array.cntArrays))
        lv_listView.adapter = adapter
        lv_listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->

//            val item: MainActivity = adapter.getItem(position) as MainActivity

            when(position) {
                0 -> {
                    val intCantare = Intent(this, cantare::class.java).apply {
                        putExtra("layout", R.layout.cnt1)
                    }
                    startActivity(intCantare)
                }
            }

        }
        lv_listView.emptyView = tv_emptyTextView

        filter.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence,
                start: Int,
                count: Int,
                after: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence,
                start: Int,
                before: Int,
                count: Int
            ) {
                adapter.filter.filter(s)
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
        })

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

lv_listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, **id**->

use this id

Comment: How do I use that? I searched on google but nothing. Or I'm just blind

Comment: I figured out how to use the Id but I still have this problem
"The problem with position is that if I search for item2 and I press it, the onItemClickListener will see that it's first in the row(position 0) and it will set layout 1 instead of layout 2."

Comment: In this case, Create a click listener inside the adapter only. Example:- https://site-valley.com/2021/02/10/how-to-create-list-with-the-image-in-kotlin/